# What type of file is encrypted by EncryptedFile

Tags: android, file, security, encryption, file-security

I'm using the **EncryptedFile** class which is part of the Android Jetpack library and introduced in Google I / O 19. I just want to know if this library only encrypts a .txt file or any type of file such as a farmware file. , Image file, video file or any large file can be encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile), it seems to be used for creating or reading a previously encrypted file. No such limitation to *.txt files is mentioned.

You can always try more and more files to discover it even further!